# I'm a teacher and I teach at/in school OR at/in a school

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

There are a lot of posts on this topic, but I can't find any answers to my question.

I came across the following two definitions of 'school':

> 2. [uncountable] (used without the or a) the process of learning in a
>      school; the time during your life when you go to a school (British
>      English)
> 3. [uncountable] (used without the or a) the time during the day when
>      children are working in a school

Source: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/school_1?q=school

I know there are better ways to convey the message, but which sentence would a teacher utter if he was a school teacher teaching students, adults, etc.? What about a janitor, director, and secretary?

> I teach at/in school OR I teach at/in a school

The above definitions concern students, and not working individuals like teachers or janitors.

I would appreciate if you also stated whether you're American, Canadian, British, etc.

Comment: I'm a teacher and I teach school http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/teach+school

Comment: @Elian - With respect to thefreedictionary, I'm a teacher and I teach *students.*  I teach *at* St. Fidgeta's Academy.  I teach *at* a small, rural boarding school.  But I don't "teach school," except perhaps quite colloquially, here in the US.

Comment: @Rob_Ster Does the following text sound colloquial to you? https://books.google.fr/books?id=c_ORomNygLcC&pg=PA523&dq=%22taught+school+to%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7q5nRtZvLAhVGthQKHSrKB_Q4ChDoAQgsMAI#v=onepage&q=%22taught%20school%20to%22&f=false; https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taught+school+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaught%20school%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I know about those, guys. I'd like to know what's your take on the expressions in question, though.

Comment: @Elian -Thanks! No, I admit that they don't. In what I hope is a friendly and collegial spirit, I see that both the links point to the phrase "taught school to-" with an infinitive indicating purpose afterwards. That sounds like a difference to me. What *does* sound colloquial is an unmodified declaration, *he teaches school.* My next door neighbor might say that of me, I suppose. But of the hundreds of professional colleagues that I've interacted with, few have said that of themselves. Perhaps we can compromise and call it "informal," here in the informal and friendly field of comments.

Comment: @Rob_Ster [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/teach) doesn't see the need to flag this choice of semantic DO as colloquial:  **teach** [tr] 6. To carry on instruction on a regular basis in: taught high school for many years. Also, there are over 100 000 Google hits for "where he taught school".  Though as a Brit, I agree with Collins (who don't have this usage) that this expression is at best rare in the UK. //  Decent dictionaries are almost always more reliable than subjective impressions: they examine corpus data.

Comment: 'Taught school' also sounds a bit folksy in the US, like working in a schoolhouse. I mean to say that it sounds old-fashioned, with most people saying "I teach X grade" or that they teach one subject or another, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to say *where* it is that you work and not *what* it is that you teach.

You have several options, but you'll need either a proper noun (e.g., Jackson Middle School) or the **countable** noun "school" and an article.  It would also be natural to include the type of school (e.g., a high-school or a language school).

> A: What do you do?
>
> B: I teach **at** a ______ school.

When you say "I work (teach) at a school" you make a more general reference to location, one which does not specify that you work inside of the school.

> A: What do you do?
>
> B: I teach **in** a ______ school.

Teachers are in a classroom, and this is going to be what person A pictures in his/her mind.

Of course, the janitor also works at a/the school, as do the secretary and the director, but should each of these workers choose to say "in a school", they evoke different mental images.  Person A would picture the secretary in his/her office, the director in his/her office, and the janitor in the hallway (perhaps pushing a mop).

> When is there no article?

Teachers are "at the school" but students are "in school" (meaning in class) and "at school", whether they are in class, outside on the playground, or in the cafeteria.

Let's say that someone (A) telephones the janitor, the secretary, or the director:

> A: Where are you?
>
> JSD:  I'm at work. -or- I'm still at the school.

Only the students are "at school", with no article.  Adults work "at the school", with an article.

Comment: "_I teach high school / middle school etc._" sounds fine to my (admittedly non-native) ears, while "_I teach school_" doesn't.

Comment: @MJF: what about "She taught school for 40 years"? IMO, the problem with "I'm a teacher and I teach school" (with no type of school specified) is not grammar, but utter meaninglessness: where else are you going to teach? A grocery store?

Comment: That sounds fine too, @Marthaª , but _school_ in your sentence isn't any more meaningful than it is in _I teach school_. BTW, I found tens of valid examples of _teach school_ and _taught school_ in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). I'm coming to terms with this expression.

Comment: @MJF: I think that because "she taught school" doesn't also say "she was a teacher", there's no redundancy, so "school" becomes meaningful: she probably taught elementary school, or maybe up to high school, but definitely not college.

Answer (score 0):

A search in [Corpus Of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for "*I teach ... school*" (with a gap of 0 to 4 words) yields 44 results, which can be classified as follows.
This corpus has five subcategories: spoken (SPOK), fiction (FIC), news (NEWS), magazine (MAG), and academic (ACAD).

- **a specific school (16 hits)**
  The possible constructions are ***at the***, ***at a***, ***at [Ø]*** (zero article), and ***in a***, as illustrated below:

> *I teach **at the** school my kids attend.* <sup>(MAG)</sup>
> *I teach **at The** Farm Cooking School.* <sup>(MAG)</sup>
> *I teach **at a** school with a high number of' gifted' and high-achieving students.* <sup>(ACAD)</sup>
> *I teach Arabic **at a** nearby school* <sup>(FIC)</sup>
> *I teach **in a** school with hardworking, knowledgeable teachers.* <sup>(NEWS)</sup>
> *I teach **in a** private school.* <sup>(NEWS)</sup>
> *I teach students **at [Ø]** Columbine High School.* <sup>(SPOK)</sup>

- ***school* with general meaning (15 hits)**
  The possible constructions are apparent from the examples below:

> *I teach summer school every year.* <sup>(ACAD)</sup>
> *I teach school.* <sup>(MAG (1 time), SPOK (3 times))</sup>
> *I'm a Roman Catholic and I teach Sunday school.* <sup>(SPOK)</sup>
> *I teach high school here at a private school.* <sup>(SPOK)</sup>
> *I teach history **in** high school.* <sup>(SPOK)</sup>
> *I teach religion **in** high school.* <sup>(SPOK)</sup>

- **with *school* as modifier (11 hits)**
  The possible construction is *no preposition* + *zero article*.

> *I teach high school English.* <sup>(SPOK (1 time), FIC (4 times))</sup>
> *I teach high/middle school students.* <sup>(SPOK (2 times), MAG (1 time))</sup>

- **invalid cases (2 hits)**

> ...*where I teach, the union and school board met for several months...*
> *... kids that I teach leave high school and get jobs...*

So, various constructions for you to choose from, depending on what you mean to get across. There may even be more possibilities which are not included in my search results, like "*I teach in Lincoln High School*" (but I guess *at* fits better in this particular one).